# How to update CreatedFrom of Journal Entry by SuiteTalk?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have to apply/attach a Journal Entry to the VendorPayment for voiding, so that I've tried 2 ways:

First is update the (RecordRef)createdFrom of Journal Entry = (recordRef)vendorPayment

Here is my code:

```
            RecordRef vPaymentRef = new RecordRef();
            vPaymentRef.internalId = "7850";
            vPaymentRef.type = RecordType.vendorPayment;
            vPaymentRef.typeSpecified = true;

            RecordRef currency = new RecordRef();
            currency.internalId = "1";
            currency.type = RecordType.currency;

            RecordRef mySubsidiary = new RecordRef();
            mySubsidiary.internalId = "3";
            mySubsidiary.type = RecordType.subsidiary;


            JournalEntry newJournalEntry = new JournalEntry();

            newJournalEntry.subsidiary = mySubsidiary;

            newJournalEntry.createdFrom = vPaymentRef;

            //newJournalEntry.reversalEntry = "99";

            newJournalEntry.reversalDate = DateTime.Now;
            newJournalEntry.reversalDateSpecified = true;

            //newJournalEntry.reversalDefer = true;
            //newJournalEntry.reversalDeferSpecified = true;

            RecordRef myCurrency = new RecordRef();
            myCurrency.internalId = "1";
            newJournalEntry.currency = myCurrency;

            newJournalEntry.exchangeRate = .911;
            newJournalEntry.exchangeRateSpecified = true;

            RecordRef myDebitAccount = new RecordRef();
            myDebitAccount.internalId = "290"; //account

            RecordRef myCreditAccount = new RecordRef();
            myCreditAccount.internalId = "25"; //a/p account

            newJournalEntry.lineList = new JournalEntryLineList();
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line = new JournalEntryLine[2];

            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[0] = new JournalEntryLine();
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[0].account = myDebitAccount;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[0].debit = 3333;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[0].debitSpecified = true;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[0].entity = vPayment.entity;

            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[1] = new JournalEntryLine();
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[1].account = myCreditAccount;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[1].credit = 3333;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[1].creditSpecified = true;
            newJournalEntry.lineList.line[1].entity = vPayment.entity;

            WriteResponse wr = _service.add(newJournalEntry);
```

As you see, I have added a VendorPayment to CreatedFrom, the WriteResponse status return true with StatusDetail = null. But when I access the Journal Entry have just created on Netsuite site, the VOID OF is empty (not display). And the type of Journal Entry is "Journal", It have to be "Voiding Journal", and don't have "Reversal Payments Applied" beside the Entry No.

Then, I try the second way : Update the voidJournal of VendorPayment to use the Journal Entry have just created.

Here is my code :

```
            RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();
            recordRef.internalId = "7850";
            recordRef.type = RecordType.vendorPayment;
            recordRef.typeSpecified = true;
            ReadResponse response2 = _service.get(recordRef);
            VendorPayment vPayment = (VendorPayment)response2.record;

            RecordRef recordRefJournal = new RecordRef();
            recordRefJournal.internalId = "8356";
            recordRefJournal.type = RecordType.journalEntry;
            recordRefJournal.typeSpecified = true;

            vPayment.voidJournal = recordRefJournal;
            vPayment.status = "VOIDED";

            WriteResponse wr2 = _service.update(vPayment);
```

With this way, the WriteResponse status still true, and the StatusDetail still null. When I refresh this vendorPayment on Netsuite site, nothing change, the VOIDED ON and the Status not change.

My Point is Voiding the VendorPayment by SuiteTalk.

I'm really stuck here, please help. Many thanks !!

Comment: Netsuite doesn't have enough resource for researching :(

Answer (score 1):

Create From field is a field that can only be set by the system. It will only be populate when transforming transactions.

Created From field of the Invoice will only be populated when you click the Bill button of the sales order and another scenario is when you click the Receive button on the PO the Created From field of the Item Receipt.

In suitescirpt

```
nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', 1, 'invoice');
```

What you are trying to do is not possible using the standard Created From field.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the previous comment is right.

What you need to do is two step:

1. Create the journal entry and reference the Vendor in the entity lines.
2. Apply it as a payment against the bill.

Consider the code pattern to the article [I wrote about writing off Customer Invoices with a Journal Entry](http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/08/23/netsuite-mass-update-with-suitescript-to-write-off-invoices/).

Marty Zigman, Founder
Prolecto Resources, Inc.
NetSuite Systems Integration
Southern California's Leading Innovation and Implementation Practice

Comment: Hi @Marty, I'm so glad that you've read my email. Thank you for that. But my situation are not resolved, because base on your link, I have to Initialize new VendorPayment that reference VendorBill , with the Journal added with. So, the new VendorPayment Status is not turn to "Voided", and the Journal added is not "Void Journal". The result is not exactly like when we click VOID button in VendorPayment.

Comment: Hi @Marty, the result that I expected is : when I click VOID button on Bill Payment screen on Netsuite, It will create new Journal Entry with type : VOID JOURNAL, and the status is : Reversal Payments Applied, VOID OF : Bill Payment Number. And the Bill Payment Status is : VOIDED, VOIDED ON : 9/2/2015 (with hyperlink to the Journal have just created). Is it possible to do ?

Comment: I am speculating but I see that a Transform is available on the check object to a Journal Entry in the SuiteScript environment.  That may get you the voided information you seek.

Comment: Thank you @Marty, I'm still researching on Suitetalk but no help.